# How to eliminate duplicate rows?

Tags: t-sql, duplicates

im back with my original query and i just have one question please (ps: I know i have to vote and regsiter and I promise I will do that today)

With the following query (t-sql) I am getting the correct results, except that there are duplicates now.

I have been reading up and think I can use the PARTITION BY syntax - can you please show me how to incorporate the PARTITION BY syntax?

```
WITH CALC1 AS (SELECT OTQUOT, OTIT01 AS ITEMS, ROUND(OQCQ01 * OVRC01,2) AS COST

FROM 

@LIB@.RTQOTA

WHERE OTIT01 <> ''

UNION ALL

...

SELECT OTQUOT, OTIT10 AS ITEMS, ROUND(OQCQ10 * OVRC10,2) AS COST

FROM 

@LIB@.RTQOTA

WHERE OTIT10 <> ''

)

SELECT OTQUOT, DESC, ITEMS, RN

FROM ( 

  SELECT OTQUOT, ITEMS, B.IXRPGP AS GROUP, C.OTRDSC AS DESC, COST, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 

(PARTITION BY OTQUOT ORDER BY COST DESC) AS RN 

  FROM CALC1 AS A INNER JOIN @LIB@.ITMCON AS B ON (A.ITEMS = B.IKITMC) INNER JOIN 

DATAGRP.GDSGRP AS C ON (B.IXRPGP = C.OKRPGP)


) T
```

RESULTS:

> 60408169  FENCING GNCPDCTP18BGBG  1
>
> 60408169  FENCING CGIFESHPD1795BG 2
>
> 60408169  FENCING GTTCGIBG             3
>
> 60408169  FENCING GBTCGIBG             4

How do I get rid of the duplicates?
thanks Bill and all the others for your help (I am still learning!)

Answer (score 1):

You can either change your PARITION BY to something like

```
(PARTITION BY OTQUOT, C.OTRDSC, ITEMS ORDER BY COST DESC)
```

and create a WHERE CLAUSE

```
WHERE RN = 1
```

or you could simply use a ([SELECT DISTINCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx))

> **DISTINCT**
>
> Specifies that only unique rows can
>   appear in the result set. Null values
>   are considered equal for the purposes
>   of the DISTINCT keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OTQUOT, DESC, ITEMS
```

Also, as an after thought, why are you seleting columns in the SUB SELECt that you are not using in your output select (`B.IXRPGP AS GROUP`)?